# My web driver does not understand xpath

Tags: java, php, select

I am working on Selenium . I am new user to selenium implementation . Can anyone help me out for my following question here : 
how will webdriver understand same xpath for different web element in a page?(Lets say button"A" and "B" has the same Xpath.)

Comment: Are you talking about HTML parsing? Be more specific.

Comment: Xpath can never be the same for two different objects. Can you either post the xpath or the html????

Answer (score 1):

For XPath, CSS, className, or any other selector that can have duplicates:

If you do `driver.findElement()`, it will find the first element on the page that matches.

If you do `driver.findElements()`, it will find all of the elements on the page that matches.

Comment: .//*[@id='secQuesAns']

Comment: Thanks for your answer here is three Xpath for security question they all are same can not run my script  .//*[@id='secQuesAns']                                              .//*[@id='secQuesAns']                                                .//*[@id='secQuesAns']

Comment: Yes.  If there are three elements that all have the same ID, you can only find the first.  This is because there is only ever supposed to be 1 of a certain ID.  You have two options: First, if you are employed to test a site, complain to the developers, and get the page coded better.  Second, write a selector that doesn't use the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Think about using a different locator strategy. CssSelectors, id and name are all supported.

Also, you don't have to use the Xpath generated (I assume you are using Selenium IDE or Selenium Builder?).  Generated XPath is often complex and not fit for purpose.  YOu can easily create better simplier XPath to find the same object.

I recommend installing Firebug and Firepath to give you an insight as to how to create and try out different Xpath and CssSelector